# Resolve all CSS rules to inline styles for in-memory document from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know that I can use `window.getComputedStyle(el)` to get the computed style of an element in the browser DOM.

But does anything exist that would closer match the name `document.resolveAllClassRulesToInlineStyles()` that would allow me to do what the name implies for an in JavaScript memory document.

Input:

```css
.warning {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div style="color: blue;">Blue</div>
  <div class="warning">Red</div>
</html>
```

Output:

```html
<html>
  <div style="color: blue;">Blue</div>
  <div style="color: red;">Red</div>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a native javascript method for this, but I know this functionality exists in many email marketing platforms to inline styles in custom emails for compatibility. That may be a good place to start researching.

Comment: @Sean: Thanks, that's an interesting lead.

Comment: @r3wt: I don't think I will benefit enough in the project I am working on to write my own solution. I think writing a solution like that might be pretty complex. I don't have a good idea on how I might go about solving that without spending lots and lots of time on it. I will likely use getComputedStyle instead, which also solves the problem I have at hand, but basically also inlines a lot of redundant styles into my DOM.

Comment: Could you compare the computed styles of your elements with computed styles of the same element without any classes? That'd let you strip away user-agent styles.

Answer (score 1):

I think JS is hard to do the inline style for html.

But you can try those online tools to do the same thing.

[Premailer.io](https://premailer.io/)

[Campaign Monitor CSS Inliner](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/tools/css-inliner/)

[Responsive Email CSS Inliner](https://htmlemail.io/inline/)

[Mailchimp CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)

```
<!-- Test Example -->
<html>
  <div style="color: blue;">Blue</div>
  <div class="warning">Red</div>
</html>

<style>
.warning {
  color: red;
}
</style>

<!-- Output -->
<html>
  <div style="color: blue;">Blue</div>
  <div class="warning" style="color: red;">Red</div>
</html>

<style>
.warning {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two packages that do what OP asks about

https://www.npmjs.com/package/juice

https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css